# How to deal with Windows Defender false positives?

Tags: antivirus, windows-defender

Lately, every single program I build in Windows is being marked as potential malware by Windows Defender.

Even just this simple Go application:
`
package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    // Arbitrary data buffer
    data := []byte("This is some arbitrary data.")

    // Write the data buffer to a file
    err := ioutil.WriteFile("output.txt", data, 0644)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error writing to file:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Data buffer written to file successfully.")
}
`
```

[produces this virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/99b4a249ca11cd74b1ac0f52d7c41dc7d34435bfc4ddf219f802980bee4c8984?nocache=1)

I don't care much about the other antiviruses, but basically everyone uses Windows Defender, which makes updating your software extremely inconvenient.

I understand it's a heuristic detection, but it prevents users from downloading and running the file, so it's the same level of inconvenience as a non-heuristic detection. Also users see "Virus detected" when they try to download it, which creates more issues.

Submitting false positives to Microsoft seems pointless, they take ages to respond, and they only whitelist the application you send them, so future builds are detected.

Any way to deal with this beyond buying a digital signature?